# Websphere MQ message redelivery

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

I have a Websphere MQ and a java app receiveng messages from it. I want to make redelivering system if any exceptions is thrown in my app. I'm using spring transaction manager, but the problem is if the message cause an exception in my app, the app is trying to resend the same message. Can i put a broken message in the end of the queue if there were some (2,3 etc) unsuccessful attempts of redelivery?

here's my spring configuration:

```
<bean id="mqMessageListener" class="ru.mos.notification.controller.MQNotificationListener">
    <property name="mqwsUrl" value="${mqws.url}" />
    <property name="mqwsSoapAction" value="${mqws.soapAction}" />
    <property name="mqwsSoapStart" value="${mqws.soapStart}" />
    <property name="mqwsSoapEnd" value="${mqws.soapEnd}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${mq.hostName}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mq.port}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${mq.queueManager}" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="channel" value="${mq.channel}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="${mq.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mq.password}" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">       
    <property name="destinationName" value="${mq.destinationName}" />
    <property name="destinationResolver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" />
    </property>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="mqMessageListener" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

here's the code of onMessage method:

```
public void onMessage(Message mess) {
    try {
        if (mess instanceof TextMessage) {
            String m = ((TextMessage) mess).getText();
            logger.info("MQNotificationListener.onMessage TextMessage=" + m);

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("SOAPAction", mqwsSoapAction);

            HTTPSend.sendHTTP(mqwsUrl, mqwsSoapStart + m + mqwsSoapEnd,
                    "UTF-8", prop);

            String response = HTTPSend.sendHTTP(mqwsUrl, mqwsSoapStart + m
                    + mqwsSoapEnd, "UTF-8", prop);

            checkResponse(response);

        } else if (mess instanceof BytesMessage) {
            /*
             * byte[] body = new byte[(int) ((BytesMessage)
             * mess).getBodyLength()]; ((BytesMessage)
             * mess).readBytes(body);
             * 
             * String enc = Utils.getProperty(Utils.FP_MIGRATION,
             * "mqrec.encoding");
             * 
             * text = new String(body, enc);
             */
            logger.info("MQMessageListener.onMessage BytesMessage");

        } else {
            logger.info("MQMessageListener.onMessage other");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(
                "MQMessageListener.onMessage Exception: " + e.getMessage(),
                e);
        throw JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(new JMSException(null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues operate on a FIFO basis, first in first out.

So two options are

- to within the application route the message else where.
- to specify the priority of the message lower and then ensure the consuming pulls message off in priority order.

Both options would require the consumer to collaborate with the producer.

Comment: Second option. Is it configured on the Websphere side or i should lower the message priority in my application somehow?

Comment: You can alter the priority in the application when it is sent

Comment: Another option is the use of BackOut resource of WMQ using BOTHRESH and BOQNAME QUEUE configuration parameters, where BOTHRESH define how many times you will try consume the message and after that parameter BOQNAME define the name of QUEUE that your message you be redelivery. In this case you can use a DLQ QUEUE where you can move messages to main QUEUE after some time or use you main QUEUE as DLQ QUEUE that enable message rotate in you consumer.